# Get SQL results from DB2 on cloud to Power Query via API

Tags: api, db2, powerquery, rest

I try to connect to db2 on cloud via Excel Power Query.

Based on [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/db2-warehouse-on-cloud/db2-warehouse-on-cloud-v4#fetchsqlstatementresults) this is format of curl request:

```
curl -X POST   https://hostname.com/dbapi/v4/sql_query_export   -H 'authorization: Bearer MyToken'   -H 'content-type: text/csv'   -d '{"command":"select * from mytable"}'
```

I tried to go via GUI but this gives me error
[image]

[image]

I am pretty sure I am not doing it right, but I could not even google how to pass my parameters.

Could someone please navigate how to assembly M code for this?

I tried this according to @nfgl answer

```
let
    body  = [#"command"="select * from mytable"]
    ,json = Json.FromValue(body)
    ,wc = Web.Contents("https://hostname.com/dbapi/v4/sql_query_export", [Headers=[#"content-type"="text/csv", authorization="Bearer XXX"]])
    ,Source = Csv.Document(wc,[Delimiter=",", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])
in
    Source
```

However cannot go around credentials ui anonymously:
[image]

When I try Web API with token:
[image]

BTW, everything works with python:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("hostname.com")

payload = "{\"command\":\"select * from mytable\"}"

headers = {
    'content-type': "text/csv",
    'authorization': "Bearer XXX"
    }

conn.request("POST", "/dbapi/v4/sql_query_export", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: You probably want to remove credentials from your question...

Comment: Those were fake one, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via GUI, command JSON must be in request content, and content-type is the one you send, ie JSON, open advanced editor and do something like this

```
let
    url = "https://showcase.api.linx.twenty57.net/UnixTime/fromunixtimestamp",
    body  = [#"UnixTimeStamp"= 1589772280, #"Timezone"=""],
    json = Json.FromValue(body),
    wc = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json"], Content=json]),
    Source = Csv.Document(wc,[Delimiter=",", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])
in
    Source
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for good direction. However still cannot pass PQ credentials UI. I updated my question with attempt.

Comment: @MichalPalko sorry can't help more